# How to store an array as a string in attribute

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I want to store an array as a string in a open_hours field. How i can do it.
Please help me.thats my code . Thanks in advance

```php
    $company = Company::create([
        'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
        'company_picture'=> $company_picture,
        'address' => $request->input('address'),
        'latitude' => $request->input('latitude'),
        'longitude' => $request->input('longitude'),
        'zipcode' => $request->input('zipcode'),
        'city' => $request->input('city'),
        'country' => $request->input('country'),
        'open_hours' => $request->input('open_hours'),
        'subcategory_id' => $request->input('subcategory_id'),
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'age_limit' => $request->input('age_limit'),
        'company_description' => $request->input('company_description'),

    ]);
```

Comment: You generally don't store an array as a string in a database; you either associate with other tables, or store as a JSON array. If you absolutely need to, look up the `implode()` method in PHP; should tell you how to convert an array to a delimiter-separated string.

Answer (score 1):

You could store it a `JSON` in the database and make Laravel to handle it (cast) as an array.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> ### Array & JSON Casting
>
> The `array` cast type is particularly useful when working with columns
>   that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has
>   a `JSON` or `TEXT` field type that contains serialized JSON, adding
>   the `array` cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the
>   attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace App;
>
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>
> class User extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
>      *
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $casts = [
>         'options' => 'array',
>     ];
> }
> ```
>
> Once the cast is defined, you may access the `options` attribute and
>   it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When
>   you set the value of the `options` attribute, the given array will
>   automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage:
>
> ```php
> $user = App\User::find(1);
>
> $options = $user->options;
>
> $options['key'] = 'value';
>
> $user->options = $options;
>
> $user->save();
> ```

So, you can do this in your `Company` model:

**app/Company.php**

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'open_hours' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Of course, you should have the `open_hours` column defines as a `JSON`/`TEXT` column:

**database/migrations/create_companies_table.php** // your migration file

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ...
        $table->json('open_hours');
        // ...
    });
}
```

---

### Update

Now, whenever you get a `Company` instance, you should be able to handle your desired field as an `array`:

**ACoolController.php**

```php
// get your instance
$company = App\Company::find(1);

// return it to a view
return view('path.to.view')->with('company', $company);
```

Then in your view:

**path/to/view.blade.php**

```html
@foreach ($company->open_hours as $open_hour)
    <p> This is an {{ $open_hour }} </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$table->json('open_hours');`only work on MySql database >=8.0, not in MariaDb for example.

Comment: @N69S that's why the documentation says `JSON` OR `TEXT` column. `TEXT` column is supported from earlier versions.

Comment: how to get in blade?

Comment: Just pass it to the view like any other variable. I'll update to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use open_hours column as json to store array values. Laravel migration has column type ->json('column_name')